# rsync include files from specific folder?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I have a directory structure as follows

Client_Site/

some_folder1/

some_folder2/

some_folder3/
    Lots of files

some_folder4/

Client_Site2/

and so on. I want to target the some_folder3 within the directory structure of each client site and only backup that folder with rsync, but maintain the rest of the directory structure as empty folders.

Is this possible? What would my include file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to do it in two steps.  Something like:

```
rsync -dv * remote:dir/
rsync -rv some_folder3 remote:dir/
```

Read The Fabulous Man page.